# Entering mm:ss: milliseconds into Google Sheets for time duration (arithmetic)

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, google-sheets-dates

I would like to enter times mm, seconds, milliseconds into Google Sheets and subtract times to determine duration. I use format> numbers > More formats > more dates and times > and apply mm:ss: ms. I enter my numbers (e.g. 02:23 44), the cell contains text not a number and the format shows "automatic". It does not matter if I use colons or not (cells G6, G7).

How can I enter times in the format of mm, ss, and milliseconds?

I've tried "duration" format, the cells still end up as text, not numbers. I've tried using "time" (hh:mm:ss AM) - the times show up as numbers and I can display these with milliseconds. I tried copying the correctly formatted cells, but then I cannot insert the new times (no place for milliseconds).

If this can be done without formulas that would be great. [Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/a/gallaudet.edu/spreadsheets/d/1OSqbevioPmvCmEqKyWjT0xEmbrMI-X5crv16DMTQNDY/edit?usp=sharing).

By the way, I noticed this question [Time duration formatting in Google Spreadsheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/98839/time-duration-formatting-in-google-spreadsheets) and reply about entering time. But the TIMEVALUE formula does not appear to have milliseconds. Any help on using the formula for getting ms would be great.

Answer (score 8):

It appears that the hours' field is required for time to be recognized as such. Enter `0:mm:ss.SSS` (assuming decimal dot; could be a comma in your locale), for example `0:22:22.222`

The default format for duration does not include the milliseconds' field, eg. use a custom one:

[image: duration]

The first field should be "elapsed" to make the format a duration format: e.g., 70 minutes will stay 70 minutes without carrying over to hours.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but I want to share my way of solving it (In case someone end here without answer).

> **Format> Number> More Formats> Custom number format**

In there you write the following:

> **hh":"mm":"ss","000**

Remember to write exactly this format, even if the hours, minutes or seconds are double ceros (00) so an example number is 00:00:22,750. If you write other thing, even using a point instead of a comma, will make it fail.

You can also play a little with this custom formats. For example, you might want a duration that shows elapsed minutes instead of adding and hour and restarting the minutes the 0, so simply use this:

> **^[m]":"ss","000**

Format the necesarry cells and it works!

[image]